# Backbone View extending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to create some combo boxes that their data is fetched from server.
They are all same but the data is different. This is render function of my MainView :

```
render: function () {

        ...

        this.$el.append(this.template(this.options));


        this.$('#Type').append(new App.Views.TicketTypes({ collection : new App.Models.TicketTypes() }).render().el);

        this.$('#Priority').append(new App.Views.Priorities({ collection : new App.Models.Priorities() }).render().el);

        this.$('#Status').append(new App.Views.Statuses({ collection : new App.Models.Statuses() }).render().el);

        this.$('#State').append(new App.Views.States({ collection : new App.Models.States() }).render().el);


        return this;
    }
```

this is the Main Template :

```
<label class="text-center">{{Type}}</label>
                    <br>
                    <div id="Type" class="form-group">

                    </div>
                    <label class="text-center">{{Priority}}</label>
                    <br>
                    <div id="Priority">

                    </div>
                    <label class="text-center">{{Status}}</label>
                    <br>
                    <div id="Status">

                    </div>
                    <label class="text-center">{{State}}</label>
                    <br>
                    <div id="State">

                    </div>
                    <br>
```

And this is my Views that i defined :

```
App.Views.SelectList = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: templates.SelectList,
    collection : null,
    initialize: function (options) {
        if (options) {
            this.collection = options.collection;
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.options);
        thiz = this;
        this.collection.fetch({beforeSend :App.Auth , success : function (collection , response) {
            collection.each(function (item) {
                thiz.$('select').append("<option>" + item.get('Text') + "</option>");
                    } , this);
        }});

        return this;
    }
});

App.Views.TicketTypes = App.Views.SelectList.extend();
App.Views.Priorities = App.Views.SelectList.extend();
App.Views.Statuses = App.Views.SelectList.extend();
App.Views.States = App.Views.SelectList.extend();
```

This is the SelectList Template :

```
<select class="form-control">

</select>
<br>
```

All of my Models are like this :

```
{"id":1,"Text":"Netowrk"}
```

But this is what i am getting from server :
[image]

As you can see only the last one gots data and surprisingly all of the data of all models got into the last one. see here :

[image]

I know if i change this render function :

```
render: function () {
            this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.options);
            thiz = this;
            this.collection.fetch({beforeSend :App.Auth , success : function (collection , response) {
                collection.each(function (item) {
                    thiz.$('select').append("<option>" + item.get('Text') + "</option>");
                        } , this);
            }});

            return this;
        }
```

to this :

```
render: function () {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.options);
        this.collection.thiz = this;
        this.collection.fetch({beforeSend :App.Auth , success : function (collection , response) {
            collection.each(function (item) {
                collection.thiz.$('select').append("<option>" + item.get('Text') + "</option>");
                    } , this);
        }});

        return this;
    }
```

It will fix the problem, but is there any better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scoping problem. This:

```
thiz = this;
```

creates a global `thiz` variable so every anonymous function in the iterations over the collections:

```
collection.each(function (item) {
    thiz.$('select').append("<option>" + item.get('Text') + "</option>");
} , this);
```

ends up using exactly the same `thiz`. Those `collection.each` calls are wrapped inside an AJAX call (`this.collection.fetch`) and JavaScript is single threaded so they'll all be created before the first one executes. That means that all of those functions will be using exactly the same `thiz` and its value will be whatever the last `thiz = this` assigned to it. This is the classic closure problem in disguise.

When you switch to:

```
this.collection.thiz = this;
```

you scope your `thiz` to the right view and everything works as expected.

The proper solution would be to properly declare `thiz` using [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) or [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

```
var thiz = this;
// or
let thiz = this;
```

Check the linked documentation for the difference.